# Adding values to dictionary do not persist

Tags: ios, swift, class, dictionary, persist

I am trying to add values to the locals dictionary in the class LocalsInformation, but the data is not persisting. I set a breakpoint on print(localInformation), and I am able to see that a new value has been added to the dictionary, but that value does not persist when I reload the app. I believe that I may be only changing my copy of the locals dictionary rather than the actual value.

```
class LocalsInformation{
var locals: [String: Dictionary<String, String>] = ["Jerry":["City":Destination.Seattle.rawValue,"Preference": TravellingPreference.Adventurer.rawValue, "Gender": Gender.Male.rawValue],"Beth":["City":Destination.Seattle.rawValue,"Preference":TravellingPreference.Foodie.rawValue, "Gender": Gender.Female.rawValue]}

let localInput = [[Destination.Austin.rawValue, Destination.Boston.rawValue, Destination.Chicago.rawValue, Destination.NewYork.rawValue, Destination.SanFrancisco.rawValue, Destination.Seattle.rawValue],[TravellingPreference.Adventurer.rawValue, TravellingPreference.ArtDesignLover.rawValue, TravellingPreference.CulturalExplorer.rawValue, TravellingPreference.Foodie.rawValue, TravellingPreference.HistoryBuff.rawValue, TravellingPreference.NightOwl.rawValue]]


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    let citySelected = localInput[0][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    let preferenceSelected = localInput[1][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
    if let name = nameTextField.text{
        var localInformation = LocalsInformation().locals
        localInformation[name] = [
            "City": citySelected,
            "Preference": preferenceSelected,
            "Gender": "Female"
        ]
        LocalsInformation().locals[name] = localInformation[name]
    print(localInformation)
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should understand very well first how a program, app, etc works in general when you code in an programming language. Your information only persist in memory as your app is running, then everything it's released. To persist data you need to find another way as `NSUserDefaults`, CoreData, etc, you should find in google `persist data ios`.

Answer (score 1):

Why should the information persist? Dictionaries are created in RAM, and once you reload the app, they just vanish. To persist a dictionary on disk you need to use a persistence mechanism explicitly. The iOS API provides several. One that is easy to use from dictionaries is JSON:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/120442/swift-json-tutorial

But you can also use your own file format, NSUserDefaults, etc.